# App location in background on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location

I want get a user's location in app background. It works fine if I use a timer of 9 or less seconds. If I use 10 and more seconds I can't get the user's location...

My `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    var myTimer: NSTimer?

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func isMultitaskingSupported() -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().multitaskingSupported
    }

    func timerMethod(sender: NSTimer) {
        let backgroundTimerRemainig = UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if backgroundTimerRemainig == DBL_MAX {
            println("test1")
        } else {
            println("test")
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication){
        if !isMultitaskingSupported() {
            return
        }

        myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0,
            target: self,
            selector: "timerMethod:",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)

        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
            () -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier)
        }
    }

    func endBackgroundTask() {
        let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

        dispatch_async(mainQueue) { 
            [weak self] in
            if let timer = self!.myTimer {
                timer.invalidate()
                self!.myTimer = nil
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self!.backgroundTaskIdentifier)
                self!.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        if backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
            endBackgroundTask()
        }
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation locations: [AnyObject]) {
        var latValue = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        var lonValue = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

Why can't I get the user's location when I use 10 and more seconds?

Comment: Have you registered for the location background mode?

Comment: yes,backgroud->location update ON

Comment: Then as long as you've triggered `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` `didUpdateToLocation` should be called every time the user's device moves.

Answer (score 0):

Because approximately after 10 seconds after calling `didEnterBackground` the app gets **suspended**.

> The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system
>   moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before
>   doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not
>   execute any code.

It's the [iOS app lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html).

If you want to get location updates in background you have two options:

- [background task](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:) - but it only keeps the app running for 3 minutes maximum
- [Run update locations background mode](http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7).